# IPv4 identification field manipulation in linux

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, linux-kernel, ipv4

When `Don't Fragment` flag is set, IPv4 RFC allows set Identification filed to `0x0000`.

I got a peer which is behind firewall that brakes RFC and block any IPv4 packets with such `0x0000` ID field. My "modern" 4.4.0 linux kernel generates packets with ID `0x0000` thus I can't create TCP connection.

How can I disallow generating this `0x0000` ID or how to manipulate this field with iptables mangle or any another way?

Comment: This is a really interesting question! I'm voting to move this question to [unix.se] since it's more about the innards of Linux networking than about systems administration. There are some people at that site with deep and thorough knowledge of Linux networking, so I think someone will be able to give you a good answer.

Comment: It is your peer who should be fixing their firewall. It is certainly breaking other connections they might desire, and it's utterly unreasonable for them to expect _everyone_ to adapt to _their_ brokenness.

Comment: luzik, could you tell what version of the linux kernel *always* sends id 0 ? I only get id 0 for tcp's first syn ack (from server side) at connection establishment.

Comment: [ipv4: tcp: send zero IPID for RST and ACK sent in SYN-RECV and TIME-WAIT state](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=v4.9.127&id=e801b695c3e749ab02ff06274ec1cd06369342ca) maybe more issues to be expected in the future with your broken peer and newer linux kernels (if you don't stay on 4.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably refering to [RFC 6864](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6864).

On a 4.17.x Linux I could see id = 0 only appear reliably for the SYN+ACK packet of a server answering a received connection, but not after.

UPDATE: OP confirmed that was the usual case in the Question too (with a 4.4.x kernel).

Probable [minimal requirement](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Mangle_packet_header_fields): nftables v0.6 . `notrack` is not needed, conntrack entries don't care about this id.

For what it's worth, here's a [`nftables`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch-backports/nftables/nftables.8.en.html#IPV4_HEADER_EXPRESSION) rule to alter the id value to the value `0xbeef` when [DF] is set and id == 0. I don't think `iptables` is able to do this at all.

```
nft add table raw
nft 'add chain raw output {type filter hook output priority -300;}'
nft 'add rule raw output ip frag-off & 0x4000 != 0 ip id == 0 ip id set 0xbeef'
```

`0x4000` here means [the `DF` flag](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.4/source/include/net/ip.h#L118).

Comment: Setting the Id to 0 has always been permitted. Citing RFC 791: **However, since the Identifier field allows 65,536 different values**

Comment: rereading between lines ok it's for the [DF] case only, because without DF, the packet may be fragmented later and then id would be needed.

Comment: I didn't wrote that, but your right, this is true only for SYN+ACK. My Kernel is 4.4.0. Thank you for this nft rule !

Comment: Some nft mangle features are only available after 4.10 but I think this one is ok (because it doesn't rewrite tcp, only ip)

Comment: ugh.. `Error: syntax error, unexpected set` I will upgrade distro

Comment: If you manage to upgrade only nftables, that should be enough with the same kernel.